# Auto completar varias cajas de texto

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Necesito auto completar varias cajas de texto a traves de una busqueda a una tabla de mysql.

He encontrado un ejemplo que se ajusta a mis necesidades, pero no logro hacerlo funcionar

En el archivo index.html esta el formulario. Introduciendo dos dígitos en el campo "matricula" hace una consulta a la base de datos y muestra un desplegable con los resultados que coinciden. Esto lo hace con el archivo buscaralumno.php.

Esta parte me funciona, al introducir los 2 dígitos me aparece el desplegable con las coincidencias y al seleccionar una de ellas se auto completa el campo "matricula", pero no se auto completan los otros 3 campos de texto.

El encargado de auto completar los otros 3 campos es el archivo alumno.php así que asumo que error se encuentra en este archivo.

No me aparece ningún tipo de error.

Agradezco vuestros comentarios.

Un saludo

index.hml

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/jqueryui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){   
            $( "#matricula" ).autocomplete({
                source: "buscaralumno.php",
                minLength: 2
            });

            $("#matricula").focusout(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'alumno.php',
                    type:'POST',
                    dataType:'json',
                    data:{ matricula:$('#matricula')}
                }).done(function(respuesta){
                    $("#nombre").val(respuesta.nombre);
                    $("#paterno").val(respuesta.paterno);
                    $("#materno").val(respuesta.materno);
                });
            });                         
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <label for="matricula">Matricula:</label>
        <input type="text" id="matricula" name="matricula" value=""/>
        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" value=""/>
        <label for="paterno">Paterno:</label>
        <input type="text" id="paterno" name="paterno" value=""/>
        <label for="materno">Materno:</label>
        <input type="text" id="materno" name="materno" value=""/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

buscaralumno.php

```
<?php

$conexion = new mysqli('localhost','tabla','111111','pruebas',3306);
$matricula = $_GET['term'];
$consulta = "select matricula FROM tblalumno WHERE matricula LIKE 
'%$matricula%'";

$result = $conexion->query($consulta);

if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($fila = $result->fetch_array()){
    $matriculas[] = $fila['matricula'];     
    }
    echo json_encode($matriculas);
}

?>
```

alumno.php

```
   <?php

  $matricula = $_POST['matricula'];
  $conexion = new mysqli('localhost','tabla','111111','pruebas',3306);
  $consulta = "SELECT nombre,paterno,materno FROM tblalumno WHERE matricula 
  = '$matricula'";
  $result = $conexion->query($consulta);

  $respuesta = new stdClass();
  if($result->num_rows > 0){
      $fila = $result->fetch_array();
      $respuesta->nombre = $fila['nombre'];
      $respuesta->paterno = $fila['paterno'];
      $respuesta->materno = $fila['materno'];
  }
  echo json_encode($respuesta);

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema esta aqui:

```
$consulta = "select matricula FROM tblalumno WHERE matricula LIKE 
'%$matricula%'";
```

Estas seleccionando solamente una columna "matricula".  Luego en javascript haces referencia a las otras columnas, pero no son retornadas.  Tu query deberia de ser:

```
$consulta = "select * FROM tblalumno WHERE matricula LIKE 
'%$matricula%'";
```

Cuando hagas el cambio tendras que cambiar tambien lo que los archivos retornan.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo alnfcm.

Comment: Entiendo por lo que comentas que aparte del código que hace la consulta el archivo alumno.php debería cambiar parte del código del script integrado en index.html, es asi?

Comment: He podido hablar con el autor del codigo y me ha facilitado el archivo alumno.php correcto ( lo he editado en el post inicial), pero sigo sin conseguir que se auto completen las cajas de texto.

Comment: Cambia esta linea data:{ matricula:$('#matricula')} por esta data:{ matricula:$('#matricula').val()}

Answer (score 0):

El error que tienes esta en esta linea:

```
data:{ matricula:$('#matricula')}
```

Debe de estar forma:

El método `.val()` se usa principalmente para obtener los valores del elemento de formulario.

```
data:{ matricula:$('#matricula').val()}
```

De esta manera debe de funcionar.

Comment: Gracias A.Palacio. He modificado la linea de código "data:{ matricula:$('#matricula')}" por la que me indicas "data:{ matricula:$('#matricula').val()}" y sigue sin cargar la información.

Comment: Al seleccionar el dato que te desplega, presiona con un clic en otra parte de la pantalla, para que te cargue los datos.

Comment: Sigue sin cargar. no se si el problema pudiera ser la estructura de la database. Todos los campos los tengo credos como varchar.

Answer (score 0):

Hola el error que percibo y que he logrado encontrar esta en la siguiente linea:

Resulta que cuando utilizas esta sentencia en la consulta en buscaralumno.php el LIKE no te va a traer nada, por lo que tendrás que modificarlo por la siguiente sentencia:

```
$consulta = "select matricula FROM tblalumno WHERE matricula LIKE 
'%$matricula%'";
```

Por esta:

```
$consulta = "select matricula FROM tblalumno WHERE matricula LIKE 
'%'";
```

Así te traerá todos los datos del alumno y te completará los campos que necesitas.

Espero ser de ayuda, saludos.